# Is there a easy way to make images slanted?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to add images to a website but want the images to have slanted edges as if its been pushed to one side at an angle.
Is there a quick easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually super easy with CSS. Transform does exactly what you need, there are several different ways to Transform elements so look through the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to find the one you need. Based on what you said I believe the skew or rotate would best fit your needs. It takes three lines of CSS to accomplish this (Updated to remove prefixes):

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whur3mp2/2/)

```
div.skew {
    transform: skewX(15deg);
}
div.rotate {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
}
```

Comment: Prefixed versions of the transform property name are not required by any current browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: It seems to make my image huge? is there a way around making it smaller! But the Skew helped a lot thank you

Comment: @LEWC You would need to post your code for that. It shouldnt change the size of the image beyond stretching it bounds. https://jsfiddle.net/whur3mp2/3/